# How do justify tab pane in sveltestrap

Tags: svelte, sveltestrap

So I have tabs with three element

```
<script>
  import { TabContent, TabPane } from 'sveltestrap';
</script>

<TabContent>
  <TabPane tabId="alpha" tab="Alpha" active>
    <h2>Alpha</h2>
  </TabPane>
  <TabPane tabId="bravo" tab="Bravo">
    <h2>Bravo</h2>
  </TabPane>
  <TabPane tabId="charlie" tab="Charlie">
    <h2>Charlie</h2>
  </TabPane>
</TabContent>
```

The problem is it defaults the tab alignment to left, how do I set it to justify,
I tried adding nav-justified class in TabPane but it doesn't work

```
<TabPane class="nav-justified" tabId="alpha" tab="Proses" active>
```

Last resort would be to have native html tag with bootstrap class to do it, but I was wondering if it was possible with sveltestrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding classes to component does nothing if it has not been implemented in the component.

But you can style it yourself.
Just add a style block and for instance, do this for centering tab elements :

```html
<style>
    :global(.tab-content > ul) {
        justify-content:center;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: oou so the we have to add global, this i exactly what Im looking for, thanks a lot man